# Why is my new schema not showing in the table properites pane?

Tags: sql-server, schema, ssms

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express and Sql Server Management Studio 2008.

I am trying to associate a database table with a new schema.

I have created a new Schema by navigating to Security->Schemas in object explorer. I right clicked on the folder and created a new schema called 'People' and set the owner as db_owner. This new Schema now appears in object explorer.

I would now like to associate a table with this schema. I open the table in design view and click on the drop down list in the table Properties pane which contains the available schemas but my newly created schema is not visible.

I have tried refreshing everything throughout object explorer. Closing design view and reopening etc. but still it isn't there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorted... in the most ridiculous way.

Apparently refreshing object browser at every hierarchical level is not sufficient.

I had to CLOSE sql management studio, then re-open it. The list of schemas had then managed to refresh and would allow me to associate my new custom schema with the table.

IMO this is rubbish.

Comment: Apparently this is still true... This is what I had to do in Management Studio 2014 to get it to work.

Comment: Apparently this is still rubbish. v17.2.

Comment: Still ass-mode 17.9.X. 2019 ya'll!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

Open New Query(or existing query window). <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd> in query window. It will refresh the intellisence cache or

> Edit > IntelliSense > Refresh Local Cache

Also check if IntelliSense is enabled in

> Tools > Options > Text Editor > Transact-SQL > Enable IntelliSense

Step 2:

refresh <kbd>F5</kbd> the Object Explorer.

it worked for me

[Similar Answer on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14957864/3615951)

Answer (score -2):

I am not following you when you say "open the table in design mode then click on the drop down list".  I must be overlooking the list on my SQL Express.

Have you tried to change the schema via TSQL?  The command is short:

```
ALTER SCHEMA "target schema" TRANSFER "source schema"."table name";
GO
```

Replace target and source schema with your schema names.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it seems it was just a problem with management studio refusing to refresh....

Comment: by open in design mode I meant right click on the table icon in object explorer and select 'Design'. The table properties pane (on the right of the screen in my workspace but is probably configurable) contains a field labelled schema and the data is a dropdown list of available schemas.You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: my properties window was closed.