# Making SQL Server Management Studio refresh objects more often

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am managing a database in ssms and it often underlines the objects in the queries and tells me that some names are invalid : "invalid object name".

But when I execute the query, it works fine. This happens when I change the name of a table and I change the query after, which is typical. If I can, I'd like to make this ssms update the table names more often, since SSMS underlining everything slows me down.

What did I do? I checked settings, couldnt find anything useful about this, yet.

Comment: Do you rename tables that often?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger dat question: it's a trap!

Comment: @StefanSteinegger During development, I'm constantly adding columns to views, renaming columns, etc., and it is frustrating to try new queries out without auto-complete on the variable I just added. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+R</kbd> will refresh intellisence cache.

Comment: didnt expect it to be this easy. lold. I'll check if this was the thing which corrects everything and mark accordingly

Comment: Would be nice to have a plugin that hooks to schema changes and does it automatically though.