# Database Diagram not showing table relation when new foreign key reference is added in SSMS 20114

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms-2014

I have three tables as follows -

[image]

***But when I add the foreign key reference, the relation is ( a straight line in the Database Diagram) not shown***.

Following is the reference I wrote.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].EmployeeDesignation   
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeDesignation_Employee FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId)     
    REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeId)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE    
;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeDesignation]     
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeDesignation_Designation FOREIGN KEY (DesignationId)     
    REFERENCES Designation (DesignationId)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE    
;
```

In addition, When I add another two tables (`Department and EmployeeDepartment`) I can see the relation in the diagram
[image]

The code for the reference is as follows --

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].EmployeeDepartment     
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeDepartment_Department FOREIGN KEY (DepartmentId)     
    REFERENCES Department (DepartmentId)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE    
;

ALTER TABLE [dbo].EmployeeDepartment     
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EmployeeDepartment_Employee FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeId)     
    REFERENCES Employee (EmployeeId)     
    ON DELETE CASCADE    
    ON UPDATE CASCADE    
;
```

***What might be the reason That the later one showing relation line while the previous one is not showing?
Am I missing something?***

Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Try closing SSMS and then reopening it again. Seems like the cache used by SSMS for some of functionality is not refreshed even upon closing and re-opening the database connection. check https://stackoverflow.com/a/4316415/364084

Comment: Ironically this works. The old adage of turning it off and on again holds wisdom.